# Refraction Depth issue

Tags: rendering

I am getting this strange render in eevee refraction, I cannot get rid of.
Any ideas?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi, Gaku, welcome to Blender SE. Please give us as much help as you can. Explain what is refracting, and show us some material settings.. and what you expect, that you are not getting.